# Problem passing string argument to MVVM LIght RelayCommand<T>

Tags: mvvm-light

I have defined a command like this:
SwitchThemeCommand = new RelayCommand((t) => LookAndFeelHelper.SwitchTheme(t));

where the string is the name of the theme I want to switch to, selected by a button click on a listbox.  The listbox button does have the theme name AFAICT.  The problem is that when the RelayCommand is bound to the button Command, instead of seeing the method LookAndFeelHelper.SwitchTheme(t) Int he debugger, I see something like the following:
-       *execute    {Method = {Void b*_b(System.String)}} System.Action

I expected to see the real method that is being invoked.  For a RelayCommand with no arguments, the expected method name is there in the _execute.

I have taken away the 'CanExecute' for this example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a typo in your question but I believe your command definition should be

```
SwitchThemeCommand<string> = new RelayCommand((t) => LookAndFeelHelper.SwitchTheme(t));
```

Other than that, I do not see anything wrong with what you provided, make sure your LookAndFeelHelper.SwitchTheme(string theme) is working correctly.